# Java Properties File appending new values

Tags: java, properties

I have an application that implements a JTree and populates the tree with a java properties file as default; The nodes are the keys and the values are the contents of the node. The application was designed to be dynamic so a JButton and JTextField are implemented to take in new values and put the values in the exists keys in the properties file.

So for example I have the line below as a default value in a sample.properties file

node=cat,dog,mice

and using the JTextField and JButton I input "rabbit" to append to the node, to look like:

node=cat,dog,mice,rabbit

I've implemented JTextField and JButton and have them working but I just can't seem to find a good way to append new values to existing keys in the properties file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `FileWriter`

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter("example.properties", true);
BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
bufferWritter.append("PROPERTES_YOUR_KEY=PROPERTES_YOUR_VALUE");
bufferWritter.close();
```

**Update**

Properties API does not support, I am not sure why you need this functionality.
You can try as below :

example.properties

```
PROPERTIES_KEY_3=PROPERTIES_VALUE_3
PROPERTIES_KEY_2=PROPERTIES_VALUE_2
PROPERTIES_KEY_1=PROPERTIES_VALUE_1
```

Program

```
Properties pop = new Properties();
pop.load(new FileInputStream("example.properties"));
pop.put("PROPERTIES_KEY_3", "OVERWRITE_VALUE");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("example.properties");
pop.store(output, "This is overwrite file");
```

output

```
PROPERTIES_KEY_3=OVERWRITE_VALUE
PROPERTIES_KEY_2=PROPERTIES_VALUE_2
PROPERTIES_KEY_1=PROPERTIES_VALUE_1
```

Comment: I just tried this, it did not seem to append to the existing key=value pair. What I want for it is to append the new value to the existing key=value pair so if i want "value2" in the existing "key=value1" it would append to that existing key to look like "key=value1,value2"

Comment: hey thanks, that solved my problem, at first the BufferedWritter just keeps appending the whole properties file on itself but with the FileOutputStream it rewrites it which is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html). 
It has very specific examples that do what you are asking.

Try:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(
    "config.properties");

config.setProperty("my.property", somevalue);

config.save();
```

Comment: It seems to be similar to Java Properties except that it actually caters to multiple values in one key but I think changing everything to accommodate to that wouldn't benefit me time-wise