# Issue with writing values to properties file in java

Tags: java, automated-tests

I am running couple of tests , and in each test I write to properties file. I am successfully able to write to properties file but it updates the file every time and deletes the previous values I store in it.
How can I write to properties file without getting my previous key-value deleted from the file. 
Below is the code I am using to write to property file

```
public static void writeToPropertyFile(String user, String aToken) {
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(user, aToken);
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter("csos.properties");

        props.store(f,"token");
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked into this a bit closer, and found the linked duplicate provided a lot of context into what should be done.  It wouldn't be proper if I took credit for an answer that already exists, so I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to read the file and puts its content into a `Properties` object. Update this object. Then re-write the object to the file.

Like this :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("file.properties"));
// work on props
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("file.properties");
props.store(output, "This is overwrite file");
```

See : [Java Properties File appending new values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337732/java-properties-file-appending-new-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the properties file first (if it exists) make the changes and then save it.

```
try {
    File file = new File("csos.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();

    if (file.exists()) {
       props.load(new FileReader(file));
    }

    props.setProperty(user, aToken);
    FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file);

    props.store(f,"token");
}
catch (Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```