# Writing a .properties file in Java destroys the structure of the file

Tags: java, properties-file

I am able to write to a Java `.properties` file successfully with this code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(input);
prop.setProperty("myProp", "myValue");
prop.store(output, "");
```

But then when I look into my `.properties` file, all the structure is gone! The fields are written in random order, and all the comments (that took me a lot of effort to write) have been overwritten with nothing!

How can I write to a `.properties` file while making sure that its structure is conserved?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337732/java-properties-file-appending-new-values) can help you?

Comment: Don't ever re-write a file you wrote by hand without having a backup or at least source control.

Comment: @Renato Agreed. Which is why I have both.

Comment: For writing them in order, see also [How can I write Java properties in a defined order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011108/how-can-i-write-java-properties-in-a-defined-order).

Comment: Please include a sample properties file in your question and also to explain where you wish a new, previously non-existing property to go, e.g. to the end of the file. In any case, out of the box comments are being discarded when reading a properties file. The `Properties` class does not have any fields or setter/getter methods for comments, so the behaviour is to be expected. The only comment you are able to write is a header comment for the whole file which in your sample code you set to an empty string. You will have to extend the class by an enhanced implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache Commons Configuration 2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Input file `demo.properties`:**

```properties
# This is the file header
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
# aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

# Database user
db.user=admin

# Database password
db.password=password

# Database URL
db.url=localhost

# This is the file footer
#
# Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
# occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

**Demo application reading, modifying and writing a new properties file:**

```java
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfigurationLayout;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException;

import java.io.*;

class PropertiesFileWithCommentsDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ConfigurationException {
    // Load existing properties file
    File file = new File("demo.properties");
    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
    PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout();
    layout.load(config, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    // Print some information from the properties file
    System.out.println(layout.getHeaderComment());
    System.out.println(layout.getKeys());
    System.out.println(layout.getFooterComment());

    // Change existing property
    config.setProperty("db.password", "secret");

    // Add new property + comment + leading blank line
    config.setProperty("new.property", "Hello world!");
    layout.setComment("new.property", "This is a newly added property");
    layout.setBlancLinesBefore("new.property", 1);

    // Save to new properties file
    layout.save(config, new FileWriter("demo-append.properties", false));
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
# This is the file header
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
# aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
[db.user, db.password, db.url]

# This is the file footer
#
# Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
# occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

**Output file `demo-append.properties`:**

```properties
# This is the file header
#
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
# aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

# Database user
db.user=admin

# Database password
db.password=secret

# Database URL
db.url=localhost

# This is a newly added property
new.property = Hello world!

# This is the file footer
#
# Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
# occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!